# Having an issue with opencart vqmod

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

Need your kind help in identifying this problem that i encountered recently in opencart. what may seems to be the problem that causes this error.

> 2017-11-17 2:48:46 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: categories_info
>   in
>   /home/*/domains/*/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage0n9nb4ewxm1o_modification_catalog_controller_common_header.php on line 115

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to contact the developer of the extension in case you bought or downloaded this from somewhere?

Comment: recently i bought 2 extension. 1 is FB Pixel and 2 is Out Of Stock extension. i guess it may come from the out of stock extension. btw thanks for the heads up

Comment: Did you rename your admin folder to something else? My customers had the same problems after renaming their admin folder

Comment: Nope i dont rename any folder, i install opencart using softaculous. The problem is causing haywire in my inventory stock number. Out Of Stock items suddenly appeared back to 1, Stock in hand 6 but when customer purchased it should deduct to 5 but not it came back to 6

Answer (score 0):

Because the error message contains your vqcache folder, the problem is probably caused by one of your extensions. In this case the first step is to identify which extension by disabling them one by one and seeing if the error still occurs.

Once you've identified which extension is causing the problem, the best course of action is usually to contact the extension developer via the OpenCart Contact Us page: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/contact